# GitLab CI: Insert stage runtime in DynamoDB table

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In the script of our .gitlab-ci.yml, we are trying to append an entry such as:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name BuildTimes --item {"BuildId": {"N": $CI_JOB_ID}, "BuildDateTime": {"S": "<datetime value>"} , "BuildTime": {"N": "$duration"} }
```

where we calculate the datetime string and duration before this entry. However, we get:

`FATAL: yaml: did not find expected key`

Could someone please suggest how can we achieve this? We also tried creating the item json within a variable using something like

`entry=$(cat<<EOF 
           <json code
           EOF
           )`

But that causes the complain that:

```
`mapping values are not allowed`.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the GitLab CI Lint tool? You can get to it from your Pipelines page in your project. There should be a "CI Lint" available. Just paste in your entire yml file, and it will tell you what it can about your errors.